# Why does the buffer get garbled?

Tags: terminal-emacs, ssh

Not sure what's going on here, but if I open a file in emacs (no window mode), and just do a search (ctrl-s), the buffer gets garbled. It fixes itself when I ctrl-l, but that's annoying to have to do so frequently.

I'm using OS X's Terminal declaring terminal as xterm-256color. Text encoding Unicode (UTF-8).

I'm ssh-ing to a VM and launching emacs in that VM.

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: I presume there's a mismatch between your actual terminal settings/capabilities, and what Emacs thinks they are. Please provide details about your terminal, for starters.

Comment: @phils Edited details.

Comment: Wish I could comment, instead of posting this as an "answer" but I want to participate in finding this solution. I have the same issue using iTerm2 in Yosemite when I ssh into an ubuntu VM and run emacs there. When I search, text gets garbled, highlighting remains, and the search information creeps up from the bottom of the screen. C-l fixes it, as for OP. Changing TERM has so far had no impact.

Comment: Make sure you are starting Emacs *without your init file*: `emacs -Q` or `emacs -Q -nw` etc. Otherwise, all bets are off - we have no idea what code you might have loaded that might contribute to the symptoms described.

Answer (score 4):

This is common problem, seems to be a bug in Emacs.

Potential solutions are;

- turn the number of CPUs down to 1 in virtual box.
- force display redraw in isearch (add-hook 'isearch-update-post-hook 'redraw-display)
- use this PPA (if you're on ubuntu) ppa:martin-trojer/emacs24-termfix

Here's some references where this issue is also discussed;

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/418546/emacs-screen-drawing-issues-over-ssh
- https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13687
- https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2014/12/msg01242.html
- http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=+17497

Comment: And here's the fix on github: https://github.com/martintrojer/emacs/commit/bdff1ff98d02f4307659c052d0b35a40a36f0706

Answer (score 1):

Awesome @user3756658. The second option `(add-hook 'isearch-update-post-hook 'redraw-display)` works for me. Text in the search buffer at the bottom still behaves weirdly, but this is an excellent workaround.